# Mysql stored procedure unrecognized data type

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When i use same query pn SQL tab it works perfectly. But inside a procedure im getting same error. Unrecognized data type. (near "," at position 67,100,135,162,190)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_special_day
BEGIN
INSERT INTO slider (status, first_title_tr, second_title_tr, sub_title_tr, button_one_title_tr, button_one_link_tr, image, starting_date, ending_date, create_date) 
SELECT status, first_title_tr, second_title_tr, sub_title_tr, button_one_title_tr, button_one_link_tr, image, starting_date, ending_date, create_date FROM special_days WHERE CURDATE() >= special_days.starting_date
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the definition syntaxically correct, add parentheses at the end of procedure name ( CREATE PROCEDURE add_special_day() ) and add a semicolon to the end of the INSERT-statement.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_special_day()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO slider (status, first_title_tr, second_title_tr, sub_title_tr, button_one_title_tr, button_one_link_tr, image, starting_date, ending_date, create_date) 
SELECT status, first_title_tr, second_title_tr, sub_title_tr, button_one_title_tr, button_one_link_tr, image, starting_date, ending_date, create_date
FROM special_days WHERE CURDATE() >= special_days.starting_date;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```